# После обновления ядра Linux, система перестала загружаться

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Такая проблема, пришло обновление на ядро Linux Mint 4.15.0-38. Но после установки система грузится и во время загрузки (когда показан процесс загрузки Linux Mint) зависает и ничего не происходит. Такое уже было раньше с прошлым ядром 4.15.0-36. На данный момент работает нормально одно ядро 4.15.0-20. Читал что желательно иметь два ярда, чтобы в случае какой-то неполадки загрузится со второго. Так вот понять не могу, из-за чего они не работают. Кто знает в чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: По какой из причин не работает, понять сложно, так как их может быть несколько. На сколько я помню система должна сохранять предыдущие версии, всегда можно сменить ядро, но только в случае "пожар" (ваш случай подходит). Ядра менять не рекомендуют. Оставьте то ядро, на котором ОС работает нормально.

Comment: Ключевые слова для поиска `grub` `lilo`

Comment: У меня подземный стук...